# Excluding a column from VB script protection

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am new to VB script and only have the least idea about how it works.

With the below code the idea is that the users will be able to edit/ add details to an Excel worksheet but would not able to delete any data without a password. One of the columns is for adding comments and it is not mandatory that each item should always have a comment. The below code will blindly protect the whole sheet but I need to add an exclusion to column N6:N1000. Would someone here please help me to add this exclusion.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sPassCheck As String

    Dim rng As Range

    Dim sTemp As String

    Dim sPassword As String


    sPassword = "12345"

    sTemp = "You must enter the password to delete data"


    'Use to set a single cell if more than one cell is

    'in the target range

    If Target.Count > 1 Then

        Set rng = Target.Cells(1, 1)

    Else

        Set rng = Target

    End If


    If rng.Value = "" Then

        sPassCheck = InputBox(sTemp, "Delete check!")

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If sPassCheck <> sPassword Then Application.Undo

    End If


    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification should do it

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sPassCheck As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sPassword As String

    sPassword = "12345"
    sTemp = "You must enter the password to delete data"

    ' Check if target is within Range N6:N1000
    If Intersect(Target, Range("N6:N1000")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Count > 1 Then
            Set rng = Target.Cells(1, 1)
        Else
            Set rng = Target
        End If


        If rng.Value = "" Then

            sPassCheck = InputBox(sTemp, "Delete check!")

            Application.EnableEvents = False

            If sPassCheck <> sPassword Then Application.Undo

        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```